# Reference POST body in the Tests

Tags: javascript, postman

I want to reference the POST body in my tests.

**Raw post body**

```json
{
    "AppName": "application1",
    "AppVersion": 1,
    "DeviceId": "UnitTestDevice",
    "UserName": "test1"
}
```

**Tests**

```js
console.log(body.UserName);
```

This returns an error saying: `"ReferenceError: body is not defined"`

How do I go about referencing `UserName` in my tests?

Comment: Where is server code where you are processing data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can log it by using:

```
console.log(pm.request.body);
```

(for the request)

or

```
console.log(responseBody);
```

(for the response)

In your specific case, let's assume that you want the request. Then:

```
console.log(JSON.parse(pm.request.body).UserName);
```